# Update query in subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form where there is string input that is an input to a parameter in a query *(insert sql injection joke here)*, and a subform that displays the query's results.

Currently the parameter is essentially `someVar Like "*" & forms!myForm!input & "*"`, but since the user can enter more than one string (i.e. a sentence) what I really want is `someVar Like "*firstWord*" or someVar Like "*secondWord*"... etc`

Since the number of parameters varies, I need to programatically generate the query. Looping through the words in the input and dynamically generating the where statement is not too hard in VBA:

```
dim sc as variant
sc=split(myInput)
dim where as string
where=""
for c=0 to UBound(sc)
where = where & "like '*" & sc(c) & "*' or "
next

where = left(where, len(where) - 3)

dim qd as querydef

set qd=currentDb.querydefs("myQuery")

qd.sql="select var where " & where

[my subform].requery
```

However, when I update the query, the subform that displays its data does not update even though I tell it to requery. If I leave the form and reenter it has the correct data. My approach seems to be wrong. What would be a better way to approach this?

Comment: The usual approach is to directly assign the generated SELECT sql string as recordsource of the subform (instead of a query).

Answer (score 1):

I would have "myQuery" saved as the base query without any `where` criteria. Then you could go with:

```
[my subform].RecordSource = "select * from myQuery where somevar like '*" & replace(myInput, " ", "*' or somevar like '*") & "*'"
[my subform].Requery
```

This does away with needing to loop through the words in the input string and picks up on [Andre's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39799904/update-query-in-subform#comment66894362_39799904) of modifying the `RecordSource` for the subform rather than trying to modify the query that the `RecordSource` is pointing to.